# Copying relevant text into corresponding tabs in Excel 10

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm working on a transportation sheet that has the following information in columns: Passenger Name, # of Passengers, Pickup Location, Pickup Time, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Comments

Within the same workbook there are tabs for the days in the week.

The 1st sheet is the master sheet where the guide will enter the pertinent info as above. 
I already have a formula (=Master!$A3 and so forth) for when they enter the name, # pax, etc it automatically copies it over from the master sheet to the other tabs with the days of the week.

INTENT:
I would like it to ONLY copy the above over from the master sheet if there is text in the corresponding cell for the day of the week.

As an example if there is a passenger to pickup on Sunday, when the guide enters the text on the master sheet, the info only carries over to the Sunday tab in the respective columns/rows. The master sheet is a running list so the days and info will all change depending on the needs of the client and the information is then broken out into the days of the week tabs to create a "schedule" for our guides as they collect the requests throughout the week.

Currently the name/# of pass/pickup copies over to all tabs with the exception of whatever text is entered into the corresponding day of the week (that gets copied over only to the tab for that day of the week with a formula).

Hoping someone can help and you have my thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a [Pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576). Put the days in the "Report filter" section and add all the needed cells in the row label.

Based on the information provided, and assuming there is only one day selected in each row, I think your setup will be improved if you change the columns with the days in it to one column, named "Day" and fill in the name of the day (or calculate it, if possible, using the `DAY` function). This makes your data cleaner.